# Free image RGB and BGR

Tags: jpeg, tiff, freeimage

I'm using FreeImage to load a jpeg and a tiff.
The jpeg is 24-bit (8 bpp). The tiff is 48-bit (16 bpp).

Problem is, FreeImage loads the jpeg as BGR, and the tiff as RGB.

How can I distinguish between the 2 so I can render it to the screen properly?

Comment: Could you, please, post your code here. The FreeImage is usually consistent on a format within one platform.